# How to check first level categories is available or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

In frontend i m displaying all category of first level.

Now I want to check there is any category available or not in first level.

I am using this code get all category of first level

```
public function getCategory()
{
    $parentCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq'=>$parentCategoryId))
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $categories;
}
```

If there is no category available i want to display a message but i don't know how to check category is available or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per magenton system,you can check a collection size by `getSize()` .it varien object.Just do like

```
if($YourObject->getCategory()->getSize()>0){
}
```